# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Key Management: Can I upload 2 policy keys and use both of them for id hint token validation?

Tags: certificate, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a custom Azure AD B2C Sign Up Invitation flow with a single policy key. The key is used to sign the token that's contained in the invitation link email and is then validated at sign up time. The cert is expiring soon and I'm trying to figure out how to not impact users who've not accepted an invitation.

The id token that we generate is good for 1 month.

I have a key container (B2C_1A_IdTokenHintCert) that has the current key. The key container is referenced in my custom policy.  I'd like to add the renewed cert to the same key container so that there are 2 keys in the on container and then swap out the cert on the web server that generates the link with the signed token.

I'd like for both old links that are signed with the current cert and new links generated with the new cert be valid during signup.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have more than one certificate inside a key container.  The system will use both to determine if the invitation token is valid up until the cert itself expires.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one value per policy key id. However, you can upload your new certificate as a new policy key, then add an additional technical profile into your user journey that validates your token hint against the new policy key. Example: Step 1 tries to validate the token hint against policy key 1, if it's not successful, then try to validate the token hint against policy key 2. That way old links and new links can both be validated.

Comment: This is one method to do what I was looking to do, however, it's a bit misleading.  I WAS able to load my renewed cert into the same key container (2 different kids in 1 key container) as the expiring cert and get successful sign ups when the invitation tokens were signed by either the old or the renewed certificate.  I did not need to modify my user journey.